# Android XML resource format/structure

Tags: android, xml

How to properly write android xml resource where object has a main ID and sub-objects has subID's

I have very good example to explain my problem. Example is written in Plist(modified xml version for iOS):

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>223</key>----main key/ID
<dict>
<key>name</key>----sub-key/ID
  <string>Bill</string>
<key>uzvards</key>
  <string>Gates</string>
<key>adress</key>
  <string>Broadway</string>
```

So i need this type of data structure written in android XML. I guess xml file should be created in Values folder and use Resource type !? Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you want. You keep the XML layout files in res/layout directory and hard-coded strings should go in the strings.xml file and referenced in layout file as @string/"string_name". If they are objects added and removed at runtime then you probably want them in hashmap or other array. You add textviews and edittext and such in your XML for input/output resources. If you can be a little more specific of what you want, I may be able to help more. Link to XML examples [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into Plist, I think my comment was a suitable answer. In your actual code, you will want to use something like a [hashmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html), for your data. Depending on what you want, there are numerous ways to set this up but you can create a new hashmap

```
HashMap<String, String> myMap = new Hash<String, String>();
```

then use put(key, value) to add things to the map which you may get from a TextView and could display in an EditText. You can also use ArrayList and many others depending on what you want to accomplish. Or HashMaps inside of HashMaps. 
Note: if you want to keep the order of your map you will want to use a linked hashmap
The res directory is where you store your XML for layouts(UI). My comment link should explain that very well. Hope this helps.